# What is the difference between AIR and a browser?

Tags: air

I'm curious what "features" are in Adobe AIR that makes it unique from browsers. I've heard that it has SQLlite on board, but what else makes it any different from Chrome's application mode (get the same functionality using [Firefox's Prism plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665))

Is it fair to call it a browser?

Comment: I'm tempted to close it based on that, but part of my question is a curiosity of why AIR is interesting to me as a programmer at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIR is technically a runtime much like Prism, and Silverlight (dunno about Chrome) for RIAs. They try to bridge the gap between the desktop applications and the browser. Browsers typically do not have disk access.

I'd suggest you go through [this](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/comparison/) link.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Air is sort of like having a web application run on your desktop as if it was a windows/mac application. It is the answer from Adobe to Microsoft Silverlight out of browser experience. There are some technical differences; for one you need to install a seperate piece of software before you can use it while the Silverlight one comes with the Silverlight runtime. Another difference is applications running on Adobe Air have much higher permissions on your system than Silverlight ones.

Comment: Not to be picky, but the Silverlight Out of Browser experience is actually the answer to Adobe AIR.

Comment: And I thought Silverlight was really their (2nd) answer to flash (ActiveX being their first miserable response)

Comment: Considering Flash was an ActiveX control in IE, not so miserable.